# Return type for Appconfig map in java

Tags: java, app-config

I have the following declaration in Appconfig

```
*.*.size.height = {
    Size_0X_3X = {
        value1 = 0.6;
        value2 = 0.4;
    };
    Size_4X_6X = {
        value1 = 0.9;
        value2 = 0.4;
    };
    Size_7X_12X = {
        value1 = 0.8;
        value2 = 0.2;
    };
}
```

Want to use it in a java class with something like

```
AppConfig.findVector("size.height")
```

what will the return value in that case

Comment: have you tried executing it?

Comment: Due to limitation of not able to test locally Appconfig related changes, not able to do so, any suggestion to do it via unit testing?